# When I import vuetify.js to my Vue project, text selection color is changed black

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using red color text in my Vue project. If I don't import vuetify.js, when I select the text, the text color doesn't change. But I import vuetify.js, the selection text color changed black from red. How can I don't change the selection text color even I import(use) vuetify.

When No vuetify css
[image: No vuetify]

[Codepen](http://shorturl.at/bkmN0)

When Import vuetify css
[image: Import vuetify]

[Codepen](http://shorturl.at/glyHX)

I'm using HTML editor(tiptap) in my vue project. But vuetify css changed the global style of my project. It make me embarrassed. When I change text color with selecting text, I don't know whether the color is changed or not. Because the selection color is always black.

How can I ignore some vuetify css in some components or Divs.

Comment: Please post some sample code where the issue can be reproduced

Comment: Add custom css class to control the color if text

Comment: In every vue project, if I add "import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'", the selection color is changed to black like above images.

Comment: Your codepen link is not working

Comment: Can't you open the link? I checked the link again. I can open it. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text selection color is controlled by the sudo class `::selection`. Vuetify has two declarations in its main css file.

```
::-moz-selection {
   background-color: #b3d4fc; /* Required when declaring ::selection */
   color: #000;
   text-shadow: none;
}
::selection {
   background-color: #b3d4fc; /* Required when declaring ::selection */
   color: #000;
   text-shadow: none;
}
```

You should set up a custom styles css or scss that has precedence over the the vuetify.css that overides these styles how you want.

Or rather than overriding the selection properties with other colors you can also simply `unset` them.

```
::selection {
   background-color: #b3d4fc; /* Required when declaring ::selection */
   color: unset;
   text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I need a solution for ignoring vuetify this css setting. If I declare my own ::selection style, I can change the text color for selection. I want don't change the text color. Is there any solution?

Comment: Yes I updated my answer.  You still have to overide the vuetify styles but use `unset` instead as the `color` property.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for. Thanks' again